# How to fix RequestError: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT while running Mocha JS/NodeJS test from behind proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, mocha.js, request-promise

I am getting the below error while trying to run Mocha JS test case which runs npm request-promise to call a REST service. I was able to connect to the REST URI endpoint through ARC client bur it failed with below error while running through organization's proxy-

```
     RequestError: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT SERVER_IP:SERVER_PORT
  at new RequestError (<Some_Path>\errors.js:14:15)
  at Request.plumbing.callback (<Some_Path>\plumbing.js:87:29)
  at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (<Some_Path>\plumbing.js:46:31)
  at self.callback (<Some_Path>\request.js:188:22)
  at Request.onRequestError (<Some_Path>\request\request.js:884:8)
  at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
  at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue with adding the following in the `request-promise` options-

`proxy:'http://PROXY_SERVER_IP:PORT#'`

I hope this helps.

Cheers,
Kunal

Comment: Could you please clarify where do you add it and how you do ?

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim I added it to the `options` while calling the REST service using request-promise as below:let options = `{
      method: 'POST',
      uri: <URL>,
      json: true,
      headers: {
       <CUSTOM_HEADERS>
      },
      body : <REQUEST_BODY>,
      proxy:'http://<PROXY_SERVER_IP:PORT>'
    };`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

var request = require('request-promise').defaults({
    proxy:'http://username:password@host:port',
    strictSSL :false
  });